# Domain argument error fix

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve three equations with three unknowns. The following is what I have, I am trying to solve for Φ, θ, and ψ.

```
Solve[cos[Subscript[\[Alpha], 1]] == cos[\[Theta]] cos[\[Psi]] cos[Subscript[\[Alpha], 0]] + 
   cos[Subscript[\[Beta], 
     0]] (cos[\[Psi]] sin[\[Theta]] sin[\[Phi]] - 
      cos[\[Phi]] sin[\[Psi]]) + 
   cos[Subscript[\[Gamma], 
     0]] (cos[\[Phi]] cos[\[Psi]] sin[\[Theta]] + 
      sin[\[Phi]] sin[\[Psi]]), 
 cos[Subscript[\[Beta], 1]] == 
  cos[\[Theta]] cos[Subscript[\[Alpha], 0]] sin[\[Psi]] + 
   cos[Subscript[\[Gamma], 
     0]] (-cos[\[Psi]] sin[\[Phi]] + 
      cos[\[Psi]] sin[\[Theta]] sin[\[Psi]]) + 
   cos[Subscript[\[Beta], 
     0]] (cos[\[Phi]] cos[\[Psi]] + 
      sin[\[Theta]] sin[\[Phi]] sin[\[Psi]]), 
 cos[Subscript[\[Gamma], 1]] == 
  cos[\[Theta]] cos[\[Phi]] cos[Subscript[\[Gamma], 0]] - 
   cos[Subscript[\[Alpha], 0]] sin[\[Theta]] + 
   cos[\[Theta]] cos[Subscript[\[Beta], 
     0]] sin[\[Phi]], {\[Phi], \[Theta], \[Psi]}]
```

I get an "Solve::bddom: "Value {[Phi],[Theta],[Psi]} of the domain argument should be Complexes, Reals, Algebraics, Rationals, Integers, Primes, or Automatic." error.

[image]

Comment: `Sin` and `Cos` need to be capitalized.

Comment: Capitalization matters. Use `Cos[]` and `Sin[]`.

Comment: Also, you need to enclose all your equations in a `List` with `{...}`. Otherwise, `Solve` is trying to interpret some of your equations as other arguments.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed the Sin and Cos but I seem to have the same problem.